# @AllArgsConstructor not working on object initialization

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, mockito, lombok

Following is the of MyService application:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyService {
   @NonNull private final MyService1 myService1;
   
   //rest of code
}
```

I have specified the @AllArgsConstructor. When I am trying to write the unit tests for the class above it fails. Following is how I am writing the unit test:

```
@RunWith(Mockito.JUnitRunner.class)
public MyServiceTest {
     @Mock
     private MyService1 myService1;
     
     private MyService myService;
     @Before
     public void setUp() {
        myService = new MyService(myService1);
        //rest of code
     }
}
```

The error thrown is:

> java: constructor MyService in class  cannot be applied to given types;
> required: no arguments
> found: 
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

But when I explicitly define a constructor in MyService, the tests pass. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Clearly Lombok annotation processing is not enabled. How do you launch your test / what build tool do you use? In case of IntelliJ: is "enable annotation processing" checked?

Comment: Annotation processing was enabled. Turns out that I was using Lombok 1.16.x with IntelliJ 2020.3. so I updated the Lombok to 1.18.x and everything works fine now.